# feof(): 3 is not a valid stream resource in

Tags: php

after i have installed windows 8 on my desktop and reinstalled aptana and xampp, i somehow can't use !feof($handle). i want to get the symbols of nasdaq stored in my $symb arra.here is an example and my error:

```
$symb = array();
$url = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download";
$handle = fopen("$url","r");
while( !feof($handle) ){
    $line = fgetcsv($handle, 1024);
    if($line!="Symbol" && isset($line[0]) && $line[0] != null   ){
        $symb[] = trim($line[0]);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

And my Errors :

Warning: feof(): 3 is not a valid stream resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\demos\screener\candleScreener.php on line 61

Warning: fgetcsv(): 3 is not a valid stream resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\demos\screener\candleScreener.php on line 62

Warning: fclose(): 3 is not a valid stream resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\demos\screener\candleScreener.php on line 66
.......

Is there a setting i have to change on the php.ini file or what could it be ?
thanks.

```
    .....
$url = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download";
$handle = fopen("$url","r");
$txt = fread( $handle, 8 );
print_r($txt);
    .....
```

prints out : 
"Symbol"

so my fopen() is fine ....

Comment: Yes, installing XAMPP breaks `feof`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reinstallation and the `fopen()` are red herrings. You're closing the file handle inside the `while` loop, before the file has been read.

```
while( !feof($handle) ){
    $line = fgetcsv($handle, 1024);
    if($line!="Symbol" && isset($line[0]) && $line[0] != null   ){
        $symb[] = trim($line[0]);
    }
    // fclose($handle); // Move this outside the while loop
}
fclose($handle); // Moved this outside the while loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my code. I had an extra file close function in the code. In other words I was trying to write to the file for a second time and it was not open for use. I had this coded in the top of my program:

```
$newFile = $local_directory . $tenant.'-'.$namespace.'_Stats.xml';
$newDoc = fopen($newFile, "w");
fwrite($newDoc, $urlStats);
fwrite($newDoc, $response);
fclose($newDoc);
```

Then later I had:

```
fwrite($newDoc, $response);
fclose($newDoc);
```

Check to make sure the file is open before you write more content.